# Asp.Net Session set error message, after redirect clear session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to show an error message on Error page.
I set the error message to the session.
Then I redirect the page and display the error message to the user and remove the session.
Is true for data transfer between pages?

Here my codes

```
Default.aspx.cs

       try 
        {
           //bla bla
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {

        Session["Error"] = ex.Message;
        Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx")

        }

     Error.aspx.cs


     {

       Label1.Text = Session["Error"].ToString();
       Session["Error"].Clear();

     }
```

Comment: Are you asking if this is a correct way of doing it?

Comment: you can use `session.abandon()` to clear all sessions

Comment: btw what's your question :P

Comment: My problem
Another error occurs before the session is cleared And can not clear the session

Answer (score 1):

To remove following will be enough:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("Error");
```

Try to make null checks in order to avoid `NullReferenceException`.